# Kafka Streams - Using An Existing State Store After Adding a New Source Stream

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an existing stream which uses two topics as its source:

```
val streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
val stream1 = streamsBuilder.stream[K, V]("topic1")
val stream2 = streamsBuilder.stream[K, V]("topic2")

stream1
  .merge(stream2)
  .groupByKey
  .reduce(reduceValues)
  .toStream
  .to("result-topic")
```

The auto-generated name of the `StateStore` is `KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003`.

Now I need to add one more topic as a source. However, adding a new source increments [a kafka-internal number](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/InternalStreamsBuilder.java#L64), causing the `StateStore` to be `KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000005`. I don't want to lose the current state, so I explicitly provide the name of the old `StateStore`:

```
val streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
val stream1 = streamsBuilder.stream[K, V]("topic1")
val stream2 = streamsBuilder.stream[K, V]("topic2")
val stream3 = streamsBuilder.stream[K, V]("topic3") // new topic

stream1
  .merge(stream2)
  .merge(stream3) // merge new topic
  .groupByKey
  .reduce(reduceValues)(Materialized.as("KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003")
  .toStream
  .to("result-topic")
```

It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm interfering with the Kafka internals because:

1. I'm using a custom name in the form of what Kafka would auto-generate (possibility of a name conflict?)
2. The set of streams used to feed this `StateStore` is different than what it was initially.

Any comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, the safest option would be to add human-readable name to this state but, as you mentioned, you are going to lose it.

I assume there shouldn't be any problem with what you did (at least until you introduce another change in code :)). ID `0000000003` is going to be assigned to `groupByKey` operator so there won't be any conflicts (although I am not 100% sure about Kafka Streams internals there).

There is also [Application Reset Tool](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html#streams-developer-guide-app-reset) that allows you to regenerate aggregations. But I don't know if it is applicable to your case: your retention policy on input topics might prevent this tool to regenerate exact aggregates.